# Is it possible to select class & class & class, not just class OR class OR class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select specific values. but I am running into an issue.

I have two elements one has X Y and the other has X Y Z.

When selecting for X Y Z, I'm also receiving the value of X Y... is there a way to make it so its looking for X AND Y AND Z instead of X OR Y OR Z?

Comment: Did you mean *"When selecting for X Y, I'm also receiving the value of X Y Z... "*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just combine them in the selector:

```
$('.classX.classY.classZ');
```

Comment: @samuk This is also how you would select that/those specific element(s) in CSS.

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't what he wants, I think this topic on the jQuery forums is from the same person: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-it-possible-to-select-class-class-class-not-just-class-or-class-or-class He once again worded his question backwards i think. Though, your answer does answer the question as written. :)